# How to debug a .zip generator algorithm?

Tags: zip

I'm trying to implement a minimal version of .zip file generation following this spec: https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT

I don't actually need compression, I just need a way to string together a bunch of files into a single widely adopted archive format with the capability to stream in file data while streaming out the zip.

So far I'm partially successful, 7-zip and windows built in zip extractor can extract them just fine, winrar and macos built in zip extractor are giving me corrupted archive errors.

I can't for the life of me find the actual problem(s?) though, as far as I can tell the .zips are built 100% to the specification but the spec is a big wall of text and with swooping changes from one zip file version to the next along with legacy attributes taking on new functions it is tad confusing.

Does anyone know of an extraction tool that can give me more specific errors than just "archive is corrupt"?

Or perhaps a zip generation utility where I can pick and choose between all the different ways of building a zip file so I can go and compare the results byte by byte?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does anyone know of an extraction tool that can give me more specific errors than just "archive is corrupt"?

The unzipada tool @ [Zip-Ada project](http://unzip-ada.sf.net) will do exactly that

```
Testing archive ko.zip

raised ZIP.ARCHIVE_CORRUPTED : Bad (or no) end-of-central-directory
[C:\Ada\za\unzipada.exe]
Zip.Find_First_Offset at zip.adb:589
Unzip.Extract at unzip.adb:667
Unzipada at unzipada.adb:259
```

By browsing the code (like: zip.adb, line 589) you can narrow down the corrupt archive issues. For building the tool, download the sources and follow the readme.txt file. There are also pre-built binaries for Windows.